# Casting a negated double to int

Tags: c++, objective-c, c

is there a difference between the following code snippets?

```
double doubleMillis = -getSecondsSinceNow()*100; // returns double
int timestamp = (int) doubleMillis;
```

and

```
int timestamp = (int) -getSecondsSinceNow()*1000;
```

I see differences in the values I get in timestamp. The first one seems to give me meaningful results.

When i just do:

```
int timestamp = -getSecondsSinceNow()*1000;
```

I get results similar to the first approach.

Comment: @Neil If you ignore the NSDate/NSTimeInterval part, it is. :-)

Comment: There, I edited the question to not rely on any Objective-C.

Comment: No, it isn't, unless you ignore the square brackets too.

Comment: @Neil Agreed, I updated the code now.

Comment: The first multiplies by 100; the second by 1000.  This is an order of magnitude different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here you cast the return value of getSecondsSinceNow() (`double` ) to `int` and multiplies it by 1000:

```
int timestamp = (int) -getSecondsSinceNow()*1000;
```

Which is like:

```
int timestamp = ((int) -getSecondsSinceNow())*(1000);
```

While in the cases below you cast the full result:

One explicitly:

```
double doubleMillis = -getSecondsSinceNow()*1000;
int timestamp = (int) doubleMillis;
```

And once implicitly:

```
int timestamp = -getSecondsSinceNow()*1000;
```

so yes, there is a difference.

Comment: Hehe, so precedence bit me. :-D

Comment: I took the liberty of updating the answer to not rely on any Objective-C stuff. Your answer applies to any 'C'

Comment: Sure, no problem, but you missed two places, so I fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Neither approach is reliable as you are casting a double which is 64 bit into a 32 bit integer. You will be losing information.

Comment: I'm aware of that risk, and I know that my data won't cross 2^31.

Comment: The problem is that I pass the double to another function which expects an int, so I'll have to live with it.